# Is it possible to calculate method execution time without a variable?

Tags: java

This is the Java code:

```
public void foo() {
  final long start = System.nanoTime();
  // some operations...
  System.out.println("done in " + (System.nanoTime() - start) + " nano sec");
}
```

Is it possible to do the same, but without `start` variable? Something like this:

```
public void foo() {
  // some operations...
  System.out.println("done in " + calculateTime() + " nano sec");
}
```

Comment: Create a `calculateTime()` that returns `System.nanoTime() - start`.

Comment: Do you have any more details why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a straightforward answer. I'm inferring from the question that you do not wish to clutter your code with unnecessary profiling code, that you may remove later. In such a case, it is recommended to use AOP. You may then weave aspects around the methods that you want profiled, and these aspects would have the variable declarations that represent the 'start' and 'end' variables.

Comment: Indeed, AOP is a good option, but I'm trying to find some other tricks, no matter how dirty they will be...

Comment: @yegor256, you may then used related techniques like using `cglib`'s Enhancer class, or `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`'s invocation handler feature. The latter is dirty, but will work if your classes implement interfaces that can be proxied.

Answer (score 7):

Not without a variable *somewhere*. I mean you could have a static variable and call:

```
CustomTimer.startTiming();
// Do something
System.out.println("Done in " + CustomTimer.endTiming() + " nanoseconds");
```

but that wouldn't be thread-safe and would still be using a variable really.

The key thing to think about is that you need to indicate the *start* time you're interested in, and something has to remember that.

Alternatively you could wrap the code in something else to do the timing:

```
public void foo() {
    CustomTimer.reportTiming(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
             // Do operations here
        }
    });
}
```

... but again the `reportTiming` method would need to keep a variable.

To put it another way: if you didn't know your birth date (including year), how would you work out how old you are?